# Catch errors from an object in JS

Tags: javascript, error-handling

currently i have a module builder. in this condensed version of the script, a body click fires `foo()` which throws an error. i would like to attach an error handler to the whole module object to catch whatever is thrown from within it, not just during creation, but also in runtime. is it possible?

currently, "foo alert" comes up in the console. i would like to suppress that and let a central logger do the necessary log. in this case, i want to see "logged" instead.

```
$(function() {

    var moduleCollection = {};

    //creates modules, stores them and returns for reference
    function define(name, def) {
        var newModule = def();              //creates the module object
        moduleCollection[name] = newModule; //store

        //somewhere here, i must attach some sort of
        //error handlers for the module
        //something like:
        newModule.onerror = function(){
            //execute error procedure (like logging)
            console.log('logged');
        }

        return newModule //return as reference
    }

    //a module definition
    var mymod = define('mymod', function() {
        //foo chokes unintentionally and results into an error
        function foo() {throw new Error('foo alert');}

        function start() {
            //a body click calls foo
            $('body').on('click', function() {foo()});
        }
        return {start: start}
    });

    //start module
    mymod.start()

});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that, you'll need to add `try` and `catch` at each level of code execution.

That is, at "definition" time, in your constructors (if present), in each method body, and in each event handler.

Also, perhaps it's just your example code, but this:

```
$('body').on('click', function() {foo()});
```

Could simply be this:

```
$('body').on('click',foo);
```

Comment: actually, i won't be in control of the modules that are created. but im the one building the module builder script. that's why i needed some sort of way to attach a "catch" to the module object itself when it gets created so that any errors that are caused by the modules, it gets logged centrally.

Comment: You can't "catch" errors in functions that are bound directly (not through your code) to event handlers. You can't "catch" errors from scripts (you didn't write) included directly into your document.

Comment: If you have access to the objects that get constructed, and the important attributes (functions) aren't "private" (out of scope) then you could replace those function attributes with wrappers that call the originals inside try-catch.

Comment: Are modules just functions? or are they Objects with methods?

Comment: actually, they are objects and they have a private scope. like in the example, function foo is private and causing the error. start is privileged/public.

Comment: Your architecture won't allow this kind of automatic catching of errors, you'll need to re-design. What you need to do, is to have `define` able to intercept the object returned by your module, walk through its keys (eg: start), obtain and then wrap the functions belonging to those keys.

Comment: tried that already. but it only wraps `start`. the problem is that the errors are not caused in `start` but anywhere, even in the private scope. and i guess you are right. i may have to rethink this architecture.

Comment: This walk-object-and-wrap pattern is usually called AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) and there's a lot of literature about it. It's not well-supported in JavaScript as _classical_ OOP has to be emulated with _prototypical_ OOP, which doesn't keep the required metadata around.

Comment: tried it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BuP2G/). it logs the error from `start` but not the one from `foo`

Comment: Yes, the `click` event handler also needs to contain `try`/`catch`. And as you don't "see" that scope, it's impossible. You'll need alter your architecture. Perhaps build an API which creates objects, adds methods, and registers event handlers (each as separate API methods).